Anthology with a story about a man being turned into a mannequin
One had a man who found himself on an island with small women with pointed teeth. Another had a man who woke up in a department store where people posing as mannequins turned him into one...

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember when you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

The second story sounds a lot like "Evening Primrose" by John Collier, but it's been in at least 20 collections and anthologies just in English.

Sounds like Marionettes, Inc. by Ray Bradbury
